# Bootstrap portfolio-item with asp dalalist

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4, datalist, portfolio

i try to use bootstrap portfolio-item in datalist 
the code is

```
<div class="row">

    <asp:Panel ID="Pnl_prodL" runat="server" Width="100%">
        <asp:DataList ID="dlst_prodNP" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dlst_prodNP_ItemDataBound" RepeatColumns="2" DataKeyField="id" Width="100%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="col-lg-6 portfolio-item" style="background-color: red">
                    <div class="card h-100">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">
                                <a href="#">Project Three</a>
                            </h4>
                            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </asp:Panel>

</div>
```

and I face a problem, what I want is like this example in the link [Portfolio 2 Subheading](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-modern-business/portfolio-2-col.html)
but the problem with me all record come like this 
[image: my test page]

so could anyone tell me what my mistake here?
Thanks for everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the link you mentioned the html should look like this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 portfolio-item">
    <div class="card h-100">
```

But since you wrap the DataList in a Panel, your html looks like this.

```
<div class="row">

    <div ID="Pnl_prodL"> // extra div from panel

        <div class="col-lg-6 portfolio-item" style="background-color: red">
              <div class="card h-100">
```

A Panel creates a `<div>` element in html. I don't know what the use of that Panel is, but a `PlaceHolder` has most of the functionality without creating a div of it's own.
Maybe that will solve your problem...